# Using LDAP for authentication, how can I safely disable/deactivate an account without deleting it?

Tags: shell, security, login, ldap

We use LDAP for authentication for thousands of users.  The primary tactic we have been employing to make a user unable to login, without removing their account, is to change the LDAP attribute "loginShell" to something like "None" or "NA", as opposed to "/bin/bash".  What this does is upon login attempt throw the user "Permission Denied."  I'm not sure if this setup with LDAP and the "loginShell" is a unix standard, or specific just to our environment here.

My question is, is this a sufficient measure for disabling an account, making a user unable to log in?  Are there any holes or workarounds in which a user could still log in?  Are there any other steps we can take to disable an account?

Comment: why not just change the password of the user?

Comment: That effectively changes their state (unable to login), but it doesn't serve as a marker or anything we can check.  For example, if we want to get a list of all users who are deactivated, we can search for anyone without a valid loginShell.

Comment: In my short memories playing with LDAP, you can ad almost every thing you wnat to a user, why not a flag disable and in the same time change there password and shell

Comment: Yeah, we could definitely add a "isDeactivated" LDAP attribute or something like that, but then I'm not sure how to perform that check upon every login attempt.

Comment: you could also move them to an unauthorized group name desactivated.

Comment: This SF Q&A looks related: http://serverfault.com/questions/176834/how-to-disable-an-ldap-account

Answer (score 3):

Changing the user's shell only "definitely" changes what gets executed if they attempt to log in and start a shell.  It does not by itself invalidate access.  So, someone might be able to run `ssh host -t /bin/sh` in order to run a command, or might still be able to log in via ftp or a web app using this repository.

You could make this work, however, by checking for a valid login shell before allowing access.  You could do this with an LDAP filter.  Or, on most Linux systems (and several other PAM-enabled UNIX variants), you could use something like pam_shells, which checks to see if the user's shell is listed in /etc/shells before allowing access.

Traditionally, shell-based login access is done by either setting the shell to /bin/false or setting it to /bin/nologin (if it exists).  Using pam_shells or an LDAP filter renders those solutions "mostly" pointless.  However, I like to put /bin/true in /etc/shells so that I can discourage shell access for some users while allowing them in with something like scp; I then put /bin/false in for users who shouldn't get any of those, and use pam_shells on the services where I want to use the shell to switch things.

Most of the time, with LDAP you can provide an attribute which controls access.  With Linux pam_ldap, the "pam_check_service_attr" option allows you to list specific pam services to which this user can authenticate (using the "authorizedService" attribute).  There's also a host-based access attribute.

But really, the answer to your question depends very strongly on the capabilities of the software with which you're connecting to LDAP. :)